# WCF HTTP Issues

Tags: c#, wcf, app-config

I'm new to WCF. Yesterday I put together my first Self-hosted WCF service. Everything was going well, however I am no longer getting any HTTP response from my dev machine. I can't even get to WSDL... I was hoping somebody could take a look over my configuration please?

host.Open(); actually works, so it seems to be running okay; it's just I can't seem to browse to any of the endpoints in a web browser on the hosting machine without a 404.

Program.cs

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(WebImageRenderer.Renderer)))
        {
            host.Open();
            Console.WriteLine(host.BaseAddresses[0].AbsoluteUri);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); }
    while (true) Console.ReadLine();
}
```

App.Config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WebImageRenderer.Renderer" behaviorConfiguration="serviceBehavior">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WebImageRenderer.IRenderer"/>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8000"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="serviceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug httpHelpPageEnabled="true" includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your ServiceHost is closed as soon as you exit the "using" block. Try putting the ReadLine loop inside.